# TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null. Why

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So im trying to make a bullet-ship hitTestObject ,but i don`t know why the variable representing the bullets.length doest change.

so the error comes from this function

```
function doShips() {
      trace("bcount :" + bcount)
      trace("_bulletsArray length:" + _bulletsArray.length)
      for (var i:int = shipArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                shipArray[i].moveDown() //what the code in the Ship and Ship2 class does -> only: this.y += 3
                for (var bcount= _bulletsArray.length-1; bcount >= 0; bcount--) {
                          //if the bullet is touching the ship

                                   while (shipArray[i].hitTestObject(_bulletsArray[bcount])) {
                                    //if we get here it means there`s is a collision

                                     removeChild(_bulletsArray[bcount]);
                                    _bulletsArray.splice(bcount,1);
                                    removeChild(shipArray[i]);
                                    shipArray.splice(i,1);
                          }
                }
      }
```

}

before that i have also a shoot function that shoots bullets and puts them in the _bulletsArray.

when the traces come it is showing : 
when i dont shoot bullets it gives me this

```
_bulletsArray length: 0
bcount: 0
```

and when i shoot it gives me this :

```
bcount: 0
_bulletsArray length: 1
```

or

```
 bcount: 0
_bulletsArray length: 2
```

so why doesnt the bcount change when The the _bulletsArray changes , when i am telling it to do so in the `for (var bcount= _bulletsArray.length-1; bcount >= 0; bcount--) {`
even worse - when i datatype the 'bcount to a number 'bcount:Number' it gives me NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are iterating from length-1 down to 0, the value of bcount will be 0 when the loop exits so that is the value the trace will show.

The null parameter error is because you remove a colliding ship and bullet, and then on the next loop of the while statement you test the objects in the arrays at the same indices as the first time. If any of the objects happened to be at the end of the array, that position would now be null.
To fix this replace the while-loop with an if statement.

In general you have to be careful when you change arrays while you are iterating over their elements, becuase the position of objects change, and you have to (like you did) iterate from the last element up to the first.

Comment: In addition, a general rule of thumb: if you're going to iterate over an array and potentially delete some of the array elements, you should always iterate over the array backwards: `for (var i:int = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Answer (score 0):

Try tracing `bcount` inside the loop. You're tracing it before the Loop.

```
function doShips() {
  trace("bcount :" + bcount)
  trace("_bulletsArray length:" + _bulletsArray.length)
  for (var i:int = shipArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            shipArray[i].moveDown() //what the code in the Ship and Ship2 class does -> only: this.y += 3
            for (var bcount= _bulletsArray.length-1; bcount >= 0; bcount--) {
                      //if the bullet is touching the ship

                      while(shipArray[i].hitTestObject(_bulletsArray[bcount])) {
                                //if we get here it means there`s is a collision

                                 removeChild(_bulletsArray[bcount]);
                                _bulletsArray.splice(bcount,1);
                                removeChild(shipArray[i]);
                                shipArray.splice(i,1);
                                trace("bcount: " + bcount);
                      }
            }
  }}
```

Try it.

Comment: try my code above and you will see bcount values changing all the time. through your loop.

Comment: You're inside the WhileLoop which is in a ForLoop which is nested in Another parent ForLoop.

So when you check your `hitTestObject` in whileLoop you remove the items from Display List and corresponding Arrays.

So the items in the Arrays: `shipArray` & `_bulletsArray` are removed. And when the For loop runs again, it cannot find the objects to check for at that index. So you get Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null for `shipArray[i].hitTestObject(_bulletsArray[bcount])`.